# Roslyn Solution Refresh

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am creating some VSIX. I have VisualStudioWorkspace service. Now, I am able to parse the syntax tree and it all works just fine. But, when a new file is added to the solution (for example as a result of some VisualStudio work), this document is not present in VisualStudioWorkspace.CurrentSolution. It works like that:

First, I get the workspace:

```
currentWorkspace = componentModel.GetService<VisualStudioWorkspace>();
```

Now in `currentWorkspace.CurrentSolution` I am able to get the syntaxt tree. Now a s the result of some work, a new cs file is added to the solution, but `currentWorkspace.CurrentSolution` does not show it. Do I have to to add it manually? Is there any way to refresh this CurrentSolution object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to to add it manually?

Yes, roslyn's design is that all objects are immutable, so you'll have to return a new solution.

There are several discussions on the github that support this fact:

https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/Bliki/wiki/Roslyn-Immutable-Trees
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7626